# Two-variable cosinus function

Tags: functions

I am looking for a two dimensional sin/cos based function with some properties. I already made up something approximately similar to what I need, but still is not exactly what I want. And I run out of ideas what can I add more to improve.

f(x,y) = sqrt(1 + sin(y)sin(y) - cos(x)cos(y))

Here are some graphs:
[this is 2d colorplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoFui.png)
[and these are 1d cuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf8bt.png). Blue curve is (0, y), orange - (x, 0), and green - (x, x).

I scaled x and y uniformly so that period in 0.1 in terms of (x,x) and 0.2 in terms of both (x, 0) and (0,y). The twice shorted period in diagonal direction is important to me.

But here is the thing I dont like: the blue curve (0, y) has maximums exceeding the maximums for (x,x) and (x, 0). It would be much better for me if the function had tha same magnitudes for all the directions. I would be really grateful for any advices how to equalize the magnitudes with preserving sin/cos like behavior and given periodicity.

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is code if it can help:

```
def func(x, y):
    amplit = 1
    lymbda = 0.1
    P = np.pi/lymbda
    Q1 = x*P
    Q2 = y*P
    E = 1
    E += -np.cos(Q1) * np.cos(Q2)
    E +=  np.sin(Q2) * np.sin(Q2)
    return np.sqrt(E) * amplit
```

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Have you a typo: do you mean $\sin(x)\sin(y)$

Comment: Nope, it was not a typo. The sin(y) is indeed squared here.